# The Lebesgue differentiation Theorem for Radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Well, I am looking for references of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem generalization for Radon measures.

I want also know about results that give us information of uniformity in the limit of the Traditional theorem.

I heard about the Besicovitch's Lemmas but i didn't see them yet.

Answer (score 1):

A standard reference for derivation theory is:
C. A. Hayes, C. Y. Pauc, *Derivation and Martingales* (1970)